# CSS Help: Centered Img w/ Text Aligned to it

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-float, alignment, positioning

I'm having trouble solving an alignment issue in a footer with css. I thought I'd try to seek some help here.

EDIT: link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X8Ej4/6/

Scroll down in the CSS to /**** Layout Style Sheet *****/ for edits, sorry the base and skeleton stylesheets weren't integrating properly so I just added them all in the CSS pane.

This is an example of what I want it to be (look at the very bottom of the footer, where there is text aligned next to the milk bottle image)...
http://dthudson.com/example/centered-footer.png

I can "solve" the problem by using absolute positioning but this isn't practical as the footer is going to be responsive (I'm using skeleton). I can't figure out how to code this concept but the idea I had is for the milk bottle img to be perfectly centered and then the text aligned (or floated) next to the img someway w/ marginal spacing between the text and img.

Here is the HTML...

```
<div class="sixteen columns>
                        <div class="center">
                        <img class="milk-logo" src="images/ccr-logo-milk.png" />
                        </div> <!-- center -->

                        <div class="left-text">
                            <p>FICTION / NON-FICTION / POETRY / ART</p>
                            <p>&copy;2013</p>
                        </div> <!-- left-text -->

                        <div class="right-text">
                            <p>CREAM CITY REVIEW</p>
                            <p>EST. 1975</p>
                        </div> <!-- right-text -->
</div>
```

And the CSS...

```
.footer .sixteen columns{ text-align:center; 
                          margin-left:auto; 
                          margin-right:auto; }

.milk-logo { display:inline-block;  }   

.sixteen .center { margin:0; }

.footer .left-text { float:left; 
                     text-align:right; 
                     display:inline; font:0.45em "Lato", sans-serif;    
                     text-transform:uppercase; 
                     letter-spacing:0.2em; 
                     color:#ebebeb; }

.footer .right-text { float:right; 
                      text-align:left; 
                      display:inline; 
                      font:0.45em "Lato", sans-serif; 
                      text-transform:uppercase; 
                      letter-spacing:0.2em; 
                      color:#ebebeb; }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: can you create a fiddle and include in your question

Comment: Use negative margins.

Comment: You should have not use negative margins @Dude. Using them isn't a good practice. Plus they cause css bugs down the road of developing.

Comment: @Donte'Trumble Then use `position: relative`, top, and right.

Comment: @Dude i don't know mate. That is the reason why I asked him to put it in a fiddle. But, it seems like he doesn't need any help because he abandoned his question.

Comment: @Donte'Trumble Maybe he decided to use negative margins. So weird that people abandon their questions.

Comment: @Donte'Trumble
I apologize to both Dude and Donte sorry for the wait on the JSFiddle, let me know if anything needs to be fixed... I've never created a JSFiddle before.

Comment: Here is the link too...
http://jsfiddle.net/X8Ej4/6/

Scroll down in the CSS to /**** Layout Style Sheet *****/ for edits, sorry the base and skeleton stylesheets weren't integrating properly so I just added them all in the CSS pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the key to the answer is using `display: inline-block`. Add this property to all three elements and `text-align: center` to the parent. Then add some other minor props and there you go

```css
.sixteen {
    text-align: center;
}
.center, .left-text, .right-text {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.left-text, .right-text {
    width: 200px;
}
.left-text p, .right-text p {
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.left-text {
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.right-text {
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Notice that I also added `width: 200px` to the left and right divs to make them equal. You can change this to whatever value you want. You will only have to make sure that the widths of contents inside each div won't cross this value and sum of two of this values plus the image div width won't go over the screen width.

Don't forget to change the order of the divs to correspond their real order in the layout.

```
<div class="sixteen columns">
        <div class="left-text">
            <p>FICTION / NON-FICTION / POETRY / ART</p>
            <p>&copy;2013</p>
        </div><div class="center">
            <img class="milk-logo" src="http://dthudson.com/example/ccr-logo-milk.png" />
        </div><div class="right-text">
            <p>CREAM CITY REVIEW</p>
            <p>EST. 1975</p>
        </div>
        <!-- right-text -->
    </div>
```

### Updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/X8Ej4/7/

Enjoy!

Comment: You sir are a saint! Thank you, works like a charm.

I think part of my issue was the unorthodox way I centered the "CREAM CITY REVIEW" text at the top of the header, I noticed when I replaced the html/css that was shifted off to the left but was easily fixed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The issue with displaying all three elements as `inline-block` and centering them like text is that the bottle image won't be centered.

I created a demo showing how I would get your fiddle as close to the sample image as possible.
All changes were added to the bottom of the css.

First I altered the class on the bottle image to `.center-img` so any changes wouldn't affect other `.center` elements.

After that I positioned the bottle image as `absolute` and centered it.
`.text-left` and `.text-right` are then each made to be 50% width with padding to make room for the centered image.

The rest is just tweeking to get it looking right.

I also fixed the issue with floated block that was getting bumped down on the right.

[Full Screen Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X8Ej4/11/embedded/result/)

[Regular Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X8Ej4/11/)

```
.footer {
    height: auto;
}
.four.columns {
    width: 25%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.footer .sixteen.columns {
    padding-top: 34px;
}
.footer .sixteen.columns > * {
    padding-bottom: 16px;
}
.footer .left-text,
.footer .right-text {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.footer .left-text {
    padding-right: 40px;
}
.footer .right-text {
    padding-left: 40px;
}
.footer .center-img {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -15.5px;
}
.footer .sixteen.columns p {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```